Interaction of pullback and the Fourier transform
I'd like to understand how the spectra of functions on a given domain are affected by (different kinds of) maps of that domain. Specifically, consider the Schwartz space $S(\mathbb R^n)$ of test functions over $\mathbb R^n$, whose elements are certain functions of the form $s : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb C$. Denote the Fourier transform of an element $s \in S(\mathbb R^n)$ as $\hat s$. Now, say I have a map $\phi : \mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, I can define the pullback $\phi^* : S(\mathbb R^n) \rightarrow S(\mathbb R^m)$ of functions from $S(\mathbb R^n)$ to $S(\mathbb R^m)$ along $\phi$ via the formula $\phi^* (s(x)) = s(\phi(x))$, for $s\in S(\mathbb R^n)$. I'd like to understand how the spectra of functions are affected by the pullback operation. I.e., how are $\hat s$ and $\widehat {\phi^* s}$ related? Are there any general properties that are independent of the specific type of $\phi$ we pull back along? What are some natural assumptions we can make about, or simple structures we can put on $\phi$, such that things are then known about $\widehat {\phi^* s}$, and what is known in those cases? For example, what if $\phi$ is an immersion, or a submersion? Examples are appreciated.

The mere requirement that the pullback is well-defined already imposes a serious restriction on $\phi$ apart from the obvious one about differentiability. In particular, $\phi$ would have to "grow sufficiently strongly in all directions" to ensure that the pullback of a fast-descreasing function be fast-decreasing.

Thanks @Lieven, that's a nice intuition about the growth of . I guess it becomes no longer relevant but that a related condition holds if we replace (ℝ) by the space ′(ℝ) of tempered distributions. Any similar intuitions about the properties of various kinds of maps $\phi$ in terms of the effect that pulling back along them has on spectra was the kind of thing I was looking for in my question.

What makes me pessimistic about this is that the Fourier transform, being based on convolution, is intimately connected with the additive group structure of $\mathbb R^n$ (in particular, the integral is really taken with respect to the invariant measure of $\mathbb R^n$ viewed as a locally compact Lie group). Any $\phi$ that doesn't have an obvious relationship to that group structure (such as an invertible linear transformation) becomes ugly very quickly.
